# Drawing shapes in specified order

Tags: c++, oop

I want to draw shapes, in specified order.Ordering is based on class of shape, say, all triangles will be drawn first, then the squares. The order may be different for different group of shapes.

```
class Shape
{   
public:
    virtual void draw()=0;  
};

class OrderedObject
{
static int id;
public:


    virtual int getId();
};

class OrderedShape : public Shape, public OrderedObject
{


};

class Square : public OrderedShape
{

    virtual void draw()
    {
        //draw itself;
    }
};

class Triangle : public OrderedShape
{

    virtual void draw()
    {
        //draw itself;
    }
};

class OrderingFunctor
{
    bool operator()(const OrderedShape * a, const OrderedShape * b)
    {
        if(m[a->getId()] < m[b->getId()])
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    map<int,int> m; //key, value pair. key = id, value = precedence order
};



void DrawAllShapes(const Set<OrderedShape*>& shapeSet, OrderingFunctor o)
{
    Set<OrderedShape*, o> orderedShapes = shapeSet;

    for(Iterator<Shape*> i(orderedShapes);i;i++)

    (*i)->Draw();

}
```

My questions are,

1. Is there any better way for identifying classes than `static int id`?
2. Is there better way for ordering, than using `OrderingFunctor`?

Comment: If you use static variable, its value will be the same for all objects. So there surely will be a better way...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  the ordering is based on class, not individual objects.

Comment: Yes, and all that inherit from `OrderedObject` will have the same value, regardless of class. Unless your `getId()` is doing something else than just return that value.

Comment: Identifying classes with `static int id` doesn't really work, so any way is a better way (as long as it works).

Answer (score 1):

(Note: you need to use C++11 to do this)

1) Can't say it's better 100% of the time, but `std::type_index` works pretty well, so you can just do something like this:

```
class Shape {
    ...
    static std::type_index id;
};

Square::id = std::type_index(typeid(Square));
Triangle::id = std::type_index(typeid(Triangle));
... // etc.
```

This way you get unique id quite easily as type_indexes can be compared and they're guaranteed to be different.

2) You can use lambdas:

```
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

...

std::sort(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(),
 [](const Shape* elem, const Shape* elem2) { // sort by z-order
    return shape->getId() > shape2->getId();
});
```

Comment: with the use of `std::type_index`, I think ,we don't need `static std::type_index id` in `Shape`, it can be used directly in the functor/lambda

Comment: @q126y but how would you get correct std::type_index from Shape*?

Comment: https://ideone.com/y0EzJ9 It works, if the base has virtual function.